# CakePHP import data into table without model

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

I'm building a CakePHP application, and I have a MySQL table which is not related to any controllers/models but I need to insert/update/get data from this table in one of my controllers/models and I want to do it with `find` function (I know I can write the SQL statement and make `->query` in my models but I don't want to do it). The only solutions I saw in the web was to connect models and stuff like that. Any solutions for my case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A model need not be used by an controller to be a valid model. If you want to operate on the table using model features, then create a model for it or use one on the fly.

You can then use that model from another model via either an association (belongsTo, hasOne). Or, create an instance using `ClassRegistry::init('ModelName');`

If you do not require the Model to have any associations, and simply want quick access to find records. You can call `ClassRegistry::init('ModelName')` and CakePHP will auto-create the model for you. (`ModelName` should be the **CamelCase** version of the table, see [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions))

Eg: You have a table in your database called `documents` but do not have a `Document.php` model file. Calling `ClassRegistry::init('Document');` will create a model for that table on the fly.

```
ClassRegistry::init('Document')->find('all');
```

or even

```
$Document = ClassRegistry::init('Document');
$Document->find('all');
```

In a controller you can also use `loadModel()` on the fly

```
$this->loadModel('Document');
$this->Document->find('all');
```

Comment: @dogmatic69 Between the two methods you provided, which is preferred for controllers?

Answer (score 0):

We can operate on table without creating Model file.

If we have table named "Holidays" then we can fetch the details as below in controller.

```
$this->loadModel("Holiday");
$result = $this->Holiday->find('all');
```